# Set DateTime value to null in C# prepare statement

Tags: c#, sql

```
SupportClass.TransactionManager.manager.SetValue(pstmt, i++, null);
```

The above codes return the following error:

> Parameter[3]: the OleDbType property is uninitialized: OleDbType.Empty.

And the following corresponding JAVA code is workable, how to do the same thing in C#?

```
pstmt.setNull(i++, Types.DATE);
```

Comment: which framework are you using? is it a connection with Oracle, right? please elaborate more your question...

Comment: The framework using: .NET 2.0

Comment: so, why you are not using [TransactionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionmanager(v=vs.80).aspx) from c#? is this TransactionManager class from Spring Framework?

Comment: The structure had been develop for a long time and its difficult for me to change. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of the implementation of your `TransactionManager` and what exactly `SetValue` is doing but for DateTime, you can try to set the value to `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.